# way to give tooltip in remedy

Tags: forms, remedy

We can able to create lot of fields and forms using remedy developer. i just wanted to know whether any options for giving tooltip to those fields so that users can better understand over the respective field.

For eg: If there is a field say **price**, say tooltip like **decimal values accepted** or something reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit fields' "Alternate Text" attribute for a small tool tip.

If you want a bigger one like in overview console table etc., run AL log and see which AL opens it.

Answer (score 0):

Hover option is available for ARS 7.6 or later, and here are some info for you from BMC docs:

**Using the message action to create tooltips**

Tooltips are brief informational messages that are displayed in response to a user action with an object on the screen. Tooltips are commonly used to provide descriptions of menu items, toolbar buttons, or other objects.

In AR System, tooltips can be applied to tables, attachments, field labels, or field data.

A tooltip can be displayed either by hovering the mouse over an area in a form or by clicking an object such as a button. For table fields, a tooltip can be displayed by hovering over a row. The tooltip displays the values for the row being hovered over, even if that row is not the currently selected row.

When a tooltip appears by hovering, it is closed when the mouse is moved outside the tooltip's border. When a tooltip appears by clicking (for example, when a tooltip appears when you click a button), it is closed when you click anywhere outside the tooltip's border.

A tooltip also can be dismissed by pressing the Escape key.
Tooltips can include URL links, which can be added through a Set Fields action.

**Implementing tooltips**

Tooltips are implemented through two types of AR System features:

- HOVER event
- Active link Message action